# Изменить state React- компонента по кнопке которая не является частью React-компонента

Tags: reactjs, button, render, state

Как изменить state React- компонента по нажатию кнопки , которая не является частью React-компонента - является простой HTML кнопкой ?
(можно ссылку на пример  кода)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто в `componentDidMount` добавьте кнопке обработчик нажатия из своего компонента:

```js
class ComponentForButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      msgText: 'Nothing',
      clickCount: 0
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    let button = document.getElementById("myButton");
    button.addEventListener("click", this.onButtonClick);
  }
  
  onButtonClick = () => {
    let next = this.state;
    this.setState({
      msgText: 'Click',
      clickCount: next.clickCount + 1
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
    <h1>{this.state.msgText} {this.state.clickCount} times</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ComponentForButton/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="myButton">Click me</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="root"></div>
```